# AdWords code working on localhost, but not on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-ads-api

The situation is as follows: I have my code running on localhost, but if I try to run it on live server, I get this:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: Looks like your application is not configured to use OAuth2 properly. Required OAuth2 parameter RefreshToken is missing. You may run Common\\Utils\\OAuth2TokenGenerator.cs to generate a default OAuth2 configuration.\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderBase.ValidateOAuth2Parameter(String propertyName, String propertyValue)\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.RefreshAccessToken()\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.RefreshAccessTokenIfExpiring()\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderBase.GetAuthHeader()\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.GetAuthHeader()\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(Message& request, IClientChannel channel)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.BeforeSendRequest(ProxyRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.PrepareCall(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Boolean oneway, ProxyRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)\r\n   at generatedProxy_1.get(TargetingIdeaSelector )\r\n   at Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201802.TargetingIdeaService.get(TargetingIdeaSelector selector)\r\n   at AdWordsCall.Controllers.AdWordsController.Get(String kword) in D:\home\site\repository\AdWordsCall\Controllers\AdWordsController.cs:line 53

The problem is I'm using GitHub for deployment on Azure, so it should just grab all the code I need.

My wild guess is that there is somewhere a place I need to include the Url as a valid one, but I redid the whole key generation 3 times now, and couldn't find it. Any idea what I'm missing?

My code here:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string kword)
{
    var user = new AdWordsUser();
    using (TargetingIdeaService targetingIdeaService = (TargetingIdeaService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201802.TargetingIdeaService))
    {
        // Create selector.
        TargetingIdeaSelector selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
        selector.requestType = RequestType.IDEAS;
        selector.ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD;
        selector.requestedAttributeTypes = new AttributeType[] {
            AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT,
            AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME,
            AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC,
            AttributeType.COMPETITION,
            AttributeType.TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES,
            AttributeType.IDEA_TYPE,
        };

        // Set selector paging (required for targeting idea service).
        Paging paging = Paging.Default;

        selector.paging = paging;

        // Create related to query search parameter.
        var relatedToQuerySearchParameter = new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter { queries = new String[] { kword } };

        var searchParameters = new SearchParameter[] { relatedToQuerySearchParameter };

        //searchParameters.Add(relatedToQuerySearchParameter);

        var page = new TargetingIdeaPage();

        selector.searchParameters = searchParameters;

        try
        {
            page = targetingIdeaService.get(selector);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new string[] { e.ToString() };
        }
        // Display related keywords.
        if (page.entries != null && page.entries.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (TargetingIdea targetingIdea in page.entries)
            {
                Dictionary<AttributeType, Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201802.Attribute> ideas =
                    targetingIdea.data.ToDict();

                var keyword = (ideas[AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT] as StringAttribute).value;
                var averageMonthlySearches =
                    (ideas[AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME] as LongAttribute).value;
                var averageCpc = (ideas[AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC] as MoneyAttribute).value;
                var competition = (ideas[AttributeType.COMPETITION] as DoubleAttribute).value;
                var monthlySearchVolume = (ideas[AttributeType.TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES] as MonthlySearchVolumeAttribute).value;
                var ideaType = (ideas[AttributeType.IDEA_TYPE] as IdeaTypeAttribute).value;

                var res1 = "{" +
                    "keyword: " + keyword +
                    ", volume: " + averageMonthlySearches +
                    ", averageCPC: " + averageCpc?.microAmount +
                    ", competition: " + competition +
                    //", monthlySearches: " + monthlySearchVolume +
                    //", ideaType: " + ideaType +
                    "}";
                return new string[] { res1 };
            }
        }
        return new string[] { "test" };
    }
}
```

The response on localhost is this:

```
["{keyword: red herring f3ae3846, volume: 4276400, averageCPC: 5647516, competition: 0.305029810905172}"]
```

This is a dummy response, because it's under a development account.

Comment: what are you using for authentication? json file generated with data or `refresh_token` using OAuth2?

Comment: the refresh token

Comment: can you add authentication code here, how are you doing auth?

Comment: `var user = new AdWordsUser();` this is the line responsible for authentication if I remember correctly. All my keys and credentials come from the `app.config` file